# AngularJS, display form error for php html array name notation in name attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I display an error message for a form input with a name like `data[Foo][bar]`?

```
<input type="text" name="data[Foo][bar]" ng-model="data.Foo.bar" ng-maxlength="3"/>
<!-- both dont work for me -->
<small ng-show="testForm.['data[Foo][bar]'].$error.maxlength">Max 3 chars characters</small>
<small ng-show="testForm.data[Foo][bar].$error.maxlength">Max 3 chars characters</small>
```

Or is there maybe any other way to map the field to the rule?

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cqYww1pPKkOuZi1gV1Zl?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="testForm" novalidate>
          data[ContactMethod][0][value]
          <input type="text" name="data[ContactMethod][0][value]" ng-model="data.Foo.bar" ng-maxlength="3"/>
          <small ng-show="testForm.['data[ContactMethod][0][value]'].$error.maxlength">More than 3 characters!</small>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
testForm['data[Foo][bar]']
```

Comment: Works now! Forgot to remove the dot. Thank you!